# Submitting binary data as a file via post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-requests

I know how to submit a post request with a file.

```
files = {'file': open('local.pdf', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Since I'm downloading the file from a response, I want to avoid writing the `response.contents` to my local disk ('local.pdf') before I submit the post request. Can I submit the file as a bytes object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) to do that.

Here is an example:

```
rawData = io.BytesIO(b"Some data: \x00\x01") # Change the content
files = {'file': rawData}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```